# Marshalling and Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, marshalling, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [What is the difference between Serialization and Marshalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770474/what-is-the-difference-between-serialization-and-marshalling)

what is marshalling in java and what is the difference between marshalling and serialization?

Answer (score 1):

There are many excellent posts on Stackoverflow on this, but if you want a simple answer here it is:

They're the same, and the terms are used interchangeably.  In the Java world, both are actually used.

For [JAXB](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html) (converting objects to XML), the term marshalling is used. e.g.,

```
       JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo" );
       Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();
       FooObject obj = (FooObject)u.unmarshal( new File( "foo.xml" ) );
       Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
```

For converting Java objects to bytes, the term serializing is used.  e.g.,

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Person implements Serializable
{
   private String name;

   public Person(String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName()
   {
      return name;
   }
}
```

So it's mostly semantics.