# What does Go's JSON package mean when it refers to Marshal?

Tags: json, go

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

Marshal, unmarshal, marshaler. Very confused. Never heard of such terms in this context.

Comment: This might help.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29

Comment: That link definitely sheds some light on the matter. Why not make that the answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for a dictionary.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From wikipedia article on [Marshalling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29),

> Marshalling (sometimes spelled marshaling with a single l) is the
>   process of transforming the memory representation of an object to a
>   data format suitable for storage or transmission.

Comment: That article points out that serialization is not the same as marshalling. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: @Brenden this question will help you ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770474/what-is-the-difference-between-serialization-and-marshaling