# Cannot run Java file with bat file due to Class Not Found error

Tags: java, selenium, cmd

I am trying to run a Java class with a bat file. I have created the bat file and, as I use selenium related libraries within the class, I added them in a folder and compiled with the help of it. 
The bat helps me compile, but I cannot run because of "Error: Could not find or load main class src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation\CollectData.class Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation\CollectData.class " 
I will post below my script and what I have tried.

My script is this:

```
set projectpath=C:\Users\Mihaaaa\IdeaProjects\tennis
 cd %projectpath%
 javac -cp lib/* 
 src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation\CollectData.java
```

My lib is located in C:\Users\Mihaaaa\IdeaProjects\tennis and my class is in the path : C:\Users\Mihaaaa\IdeaProjects\tennis\src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation.
After running the bat, I tried the following commands, all with the class not found error:

```
java -classpath . src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation\CollectData.class ( from the tennis folder)

java src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation\CollectData.class ( from the tennis folder)

java -classpath . com.findyourbet.tennis.automation.CollectData ( from the automation folder and also from other folders as well )

java -classpath . CollectData.java ( from the folder where the class is, automation)

java -cp . com.findyourbet.tennis.automation.CollectData ( from automation folder)

java -cp . CollectData.class ( from automation folder)
```

None of these worked. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is a class path in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265463/what-exactly-is-a-class-path-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Does your `CollectData` class contain a `public static void main(String[] args) {}` method?

Apart from that I would suggest you build a structure like:

- `src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation\CollectData.class`
- `lib\*.jar` (put your dependencies there, i.e. the selenium jars)

Then running `java -classpath lib src\main\java\com\findyourbet\tennis\automation\CollectData.class` from the top level folder (containing `src` and `lib`) should work.