# Whats the difference between Marshaling/Unmarshaling Vs Serialization/Deserialization?

Tags: serialization, marshalling

1. Do both terms mean the same?
2. If not, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)#Comparison_with_serialization

Comment: In general, they are two pairs of terms for basically the same process.  Some system or other may make a distinction, but without more context, they're "the same".

Comment: I always thought the marshals were responsible for apprehending wanted fugitives, providing protection for the federal judiciary, transporting federal prisoners, protecting endangered federal witnesses and managing assets seized from criminal enterprises!?

Comment: @Swordfish Perhaps the difference is `printf("%d", strcmp("Marshaling", "Marshaling");`?  ;-)

Comment: Why is it tagged `Go`? Do you expect some Go-specific answer?

Comment: @leaf behop Go specific answer would be good to have... but this is not a Go only question... applies to all to languages...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Serialization and Marshaling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770474/what-is-the-difference-between-serialization-and-marshaling)

Answer (score 1):

I use the term "marshaling" to mean "putting data/arguments in a form where they can pass through an interface that only accepts particular forms", whereas "serializing" specifically means "representing data with a byte stream". That is, serialization is one approach to marshaling, but also has uses outside the domain of what I would call marshaling.

Some examples of marshaling that aren't serialization:

- Putting arguments to a syscall in the registers that the kernel syscall entry point accepts. (I wouldn't call this serialization because there's no abstract order between the registers, and because some of the data might lie outside of the actual registers, being pointed to by them instead.)
- Building a tree structure from a JSON or XML source to pass to an interface that needs a tree. (This isn't serialization because the form is language-level objects with references between them, not a stream of bytes.)
- Passing data back and forth between a host application and an embedded language (like Lua).

Comment: Is Marshaling/Unmarshaling language specific while Serialization/Deserialization? is language independent?

Comment: @akh: In the sense I use the words, language has nothing to do with either.

Comment: "putting data/arguments in a form where they can pass through an interface that only accepts particular forms" - Can you elaborate with an example?