# What is the return type of document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript

What is the type of the variable "element" in this snippet?
I thought it is a number (an ID or something), but now, I have no idea.
The code works, but I don't understand, why the var element can be used in a for cycle, like an array. Is there any explanation about this?

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function showAtrributes() {
                var element = document.getElementById("videos");
                var listAttributes = "";
                for(var attribute in element) {
                    var valueOfAtrrib = element.getAttribute(attribute);
                    listAttributes = listAttributes + attribute + ": " + valueOfAttrib + "\n";
                }
                alert(listAttributes);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns an `HTMLElement` or `null`

Comment: @MikaelLennholm: `Element`, not `HTMLElement`: https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nonelementparentnode

Answer (score 5):

> The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID
>   attribute with the specified value.
>   [....]
>   Returns null if no elements with the specified ID exists.

So it returns an HTMLElement Object

[source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

Answer (score 5):

> What is the return type of document.getElementById()

`Element`. It returns a reference to the actual object for the element in the DOM (or `null` if none was found with that `id`). Details:

- [Spec for `Element`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-element)
- [Spec for `getElementById`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#nonelementparentnode)
- [`Element` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)
- [`getElementById` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

> I thought it is a number (an ID or something)

No, that's `"video"` (the string you used to look it up). It's also accessible from the `id` property of the Element object.

> The code works, but I don't understand, why the var element can be used in a for cycle, like an array.

`for-in` isn't primarily for use on arrays, it's for use on *objects*. The only reason it works on arrays is that arrays are objects. (See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) and [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more on that.) DOM elements are objects, so you can loop through their enumerable properties via `for-in`.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of **document.getElementById()** is Element Object or *null*. Please Refer the following link from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are really questioning why the for loop works, not what kind of object getElementById returns. Read this article:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

The for( var in ....) syntax causes Javascript to iterate over the properties of the object specified by ....

Answer (score 0):

The return type can be anything that the programmer of a Web Browser defines to the JS VM library used, to create a specific implementation of Javascript. For instance, the webcwebbrowser which uses SpiderMonkey returns a JSObject of HTMLElement JSClass which it gets by calling `CreateJSObject` on the underlying internal HTMLElement object. The JSObject is the internal VM library representation of objects visible to JS scripts, such as a HTMLElement. A HTMLElement in a script is actually accessing a JSObject logically instantiated from the HTMLElement JSClass, where JSObject and JSClasses are C++ classes. The HTMLElement JSObject also has a corresponding C++ native marshalled object of class HTMLElement.